# Char Star Array parameter not terminating correctly

Tags: c++, char, sizeof

I'm writing a C++ app for windows console and it get parameters and "casts" them as a char*[].  meaning I changed this:

```
int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
```

to this:

```
int _tmain(int argc, char* argv[])
```

Now when I parse it, I can't seem to find the end of the each parameter. If I get argv[1] it just returns the dash ('-'). I tried looping through the characters using sizeof like this:

```
    for(j=0; j<sizeof(argsIn[i]); j++)
    {
        std::cout<<argsIn[i][j];
    }
```

the output here will put spaces between each character and output exactly 4 character total each time co if the command was `>cmd.exe -d frank` this would output `f r` when i=3. I also tried checking for the null charcter like this:

```
    while(argsIn[i][j] != '\0')
    {
        std::cout<<argsIn[i][j];
        j++;
    }
```

this method only outputs the first character. So in the above example, when i=3 we would just get `f` Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you are trying to interpret [UTF-16](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-16) characters as ASCII. Are you compiling your code as Unicode?

If you need your parameters as ASCII, either compile your code as ASCII, or keep `_TCHAR*` and use [`WideCharToMultiByte()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd374130%28VS.85%29.aspx) to convert the arguments.

Answer (score 0):

Because your program is Unicode.
You should change the main syntax to:

```
int _tmain(int argc, wchar_t* argv[])
```

In Unicode each character has two bytes. For English character second byte is always NULL.

Comment: I think he should use the original syntax, with `_TCHAR*` as that matches the function signature of `_tmain`.